# Конвертация unsighed char в char*;

Tags: c++, char

Надо представить десятичное число в unsigned char и реализовать операции сложения. вычитания, умножения и деления.

Число вроде бы представил, но с операциями проблема. Выдает ошибку `error C2664: 'int atoi(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned char [100]' to 'const char *'` в строчках

```
    a = atoi(obj1.dec) + atoi(obj2.dec);
    b = atoi(obj1.dec) - atoi(obj2.dec);
    c = atoi(obj1.dec) * atoi(obj2.dec);
    d = atoi(obj1.dec) / atoi(obj2.dec);
```

Насколько я понял это из-за того, что у меня объекты класс типа char* а само число unsigned char. Как избавиться это этой ошибки?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class oper;

class decimal
{
    unsigned char dec[100];
    size_t size;
    friend oper;
public:
    decimal(char*);
};

decimal::decimal(char* get)
{
    size = strlen(get);
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--, get++)
    {
        dec[i] = *get;// или просто dec[i] = *get;
        cout << dec[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

class oper
{
    unsigned char *slozh;
    unsigned char *vich;
    unsigned char *del;
    unsigned char *umn;
public:
    oper(decimal, decimal);
};

oper::oper(decimal obj1, decimal obj2)
{
    char* sl;
    char* vi;
    char* de;
    char* um;
    int a, b, c, d;
    a = atoi(obj1.dec) + atoi(obj2.dec);
    b = atoi(obj1.dec) - atoi(obj2.dec);
    c = atoi(obj1.dec) * atoi(obj2.dec);
    d = atoi(obj1.dec) / atoi(obj2.dec);
    sl = itoa(a);
    vi = itoa(b);
    de = itoa(c);
    um = itoa(d);


}

int main()
{
    //cout << "Vvedite 2 chisla: " << endl;
    //char* a;
    //char* b;
    //a = b = NULL;
    //cin >> a >> b;
    //decimal d1(a);
    //decimal d2(b);
    decimal a = "123321";
    decimal b = "123456";

    oper o(a, b);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

само задание: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: atoi((const char*)&obj1.dec)

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто пойти по пути приведения:

```
a = atoi((char*)obj1.dec) + atoi((char*)obj2.dec);
b = atoi((char*)obj1.dec) - atoi((char*)obj2.dec);
c = atoi((char*)obj1.dec) * atoi((char*)obj2.dec);
d = atoi((char*)obj1.dec) / atoi((char*)obj2.dec);
```

Но!
Зачем вам вообще `unsigned char dec[100];`? Почему он **должен** быть `unsigned`? Лично я не вижу ни одной для этого причины, зато сразу несколько - для `char dec[100];`. Вам не нужно будет выполнять приведение типов, в `dec[i] = *get;` будет однотипное присваивание (кстати, а завершить строку нулевым символом вы не хотите?). Так что подумайте о том, чтоб просто убрать `unsigned`...

Да, и `itoa` у вас вызывается не так, как нужно. Но это уже второй вопрос :) - как и функционирование программы (я его не смотрел).

Comment: unsigned потому что задание такое. сам бы я так не делал конечно. а itoa я уже понял, что не работает, вот сейчас как раз занимаюсь тем, что исправляю это

Comment: Послушайте, если именно `unsigned` - а оно тут ни к чему - может, у вас само задание вами не так понято?

Comment: я прикрепил задание к своему вопросу. посмотрите пожалуйста, вдруг действительно не так понял)

Comment: кстати, а завершить строку нулевым символом - это как?

Comment: Теперь я снимаю свое замечание о необходимости завершающего нулевого символа :) , но - мне кажется, вы не так поняли. Потому что мне кажется, что (исходя из 100 элементов) в задании имеется в виду реализация длинной арифметики - до 100-значных чисел. С чем, понятно, никакие `atоi/itoa` не справятся. Так что я бы рекомендовал вам уточнить... Соответственно, тогда в массиве хранятся не символы `'0','1',...`, а именно значения - 0, 1, 2...

Comment: так, если отбросить класс oper, то в массив `dec` и записываются  значения. я же в функции `main` присваиваю нужные мне значения, и они и записываются в `dec`

Comment: Ну запишите в `dec` что-то тридцатизначное и сложите с чем-то таким же тридцатизначным - и убедитесь, что оно не работает...